# How to select the correct material for wire-wound resistors?

Tags: resistors, component-selection

There are many resistors wires like nickel chrome wires, ferros chrome wire, nickel copper wires, etc.

All the wires gives us the desired resistance in resistors.

How can we select the best wires for resistors?

What are the parameters for selection of wires for wire wound resistors?

Comment: I have a long time ago selected the most stable material I could find and since then my rolls of isaohm are nearly empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best wire for a resistor is one that meets its specifications.

The two most important specs for a power resistor are the maximum operating temperature, and the temperature coefficient.

Precision resistors, so current shunts and the like, will require a low tempco.

Voltage droppers, capacitor dischargers, room heaters, do not require a good temperature coefficient of resistance, but will usually benefit from high temperature operation, as this can reduce their size.

Tying everything together is cost. The earliest resistance wires were binary alloys, nichrome etc. More recently, quaternary alloys have allowed lower tempco wires, at a higher cost. Generally, if you demands higher specifications, you have to use a more expensive alloy.

Answer (score 2):

Bulk resistivity, temperature stability, heat resistance, price.

Nichrome is pretty good on all counts.

Manganin has a lower thermal coefficiemt of resistance, but melts at lower temperature and costs more.

so common resistors usually use nichrome, while precision resistors use manganin.